# LanguagesResource.getName() method return null value

Tags: google-translate

I'm a new user to Google Cloud API and I'm working with Google Cloud Translation API v2 (r51). I tried to call LanguagesResource.getName() to get human readable language names to show all supported languages but I always get null value. Can you help me fix this. Thank you.
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Translate translate = createTranslateService();
        Translate.Languages.List request = translate.languages().list();
        LanguagesListResponse response = request.execute();
        List<LanguagesResource> list = response.getLanguages();
        for(LanguagesResource item : list) {
            System.out.println(item.getName());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by calling setTarget() method of object request. The code is like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Translate translate = createTranslateService();
        Translate.Languages.List request = translate.languages().list();
        request.setTarget("en");
        LanguagesListResponse response = request.execute();
        List<LanguagesResource> list = response.getLanguages();
        for(LanguagesResource item : list) {
            System.out.println(item.getName());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```